# Can't Right Click in Citrix Receiver on MacOS Macbook

Tags: macos-catalina, right-click, citrix-receiver

I'm using Citrix Receiver on my macbook which has MacOS Catalina. I cannot seem to right click on my Windows desktop that I'm remoted into. I have tried everything! I've enabled right click on my trackpad. I've tried Ctrl+Click, Command+Click, Ctrl+Double Click, etc.  Anyone experienced this issue? Please help! :)